# WebRTC not available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, object-detection

**Running examples of js-objectdetect from below link:**

> http://mtschirs.github.io/js-objectdetect/examples/example_sunglasses.htm

But on running it displays an alerts "WebRTC not Available"

Tried enabling WebRTC from chrome://flags/ And Running below command:

```
chrome.exe --enable-logging --vmodule=*/webrtc/*=2,*/libjingle/*=2,*=-2 --no-sandbox
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the relevant code in compatibility.js

```
    getUserMedia = function(options, success, error) {
        var getUserMedia =
            window.navigator.getUserMedia ||
            window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            function(options, success, error) {
                error();
            };

        return getUserMedia.call(window.navigator, options, success, error);
    };
```

Then in the HTML, you can find the following code:

```
        compatibility.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
            try {
                video.src = compatibility.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            } catch (error) {
                video.src = stream;
            }
            compatibility.requestAnimationFrame(play);
        }, function (error) {
            alert('WebRTC not available');
        });
```

If you run the page in a current version of Chrome, you will get the following warning, though:

> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

In other words, you need to use https://mtschirs.github.io/js-objectdetect/examples/example_sunglasses.htm (note the http**s**) in order for it to work.

Comment: There should also be a note about the fact that `navigator.getUserMedia` is beign deprecated, in favor to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` API : this whole lib seems outdated.

Comment: @Kaiido That is true. However, the browser support for both of them is lacking. It might be better to use a library that has a fallback to Flash (e.g. https://github.com/amw/jpeg_camera).

Comment: Browsers that don't support gUM (today's up to date, only safari) won't support RTC communication either.

Answer (score 0):

please use this :

```
    navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    /* use the stream */
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    /* handle the error */
  });
```

instead simple get user media

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).